# What's the best way to insert data in between a hdf5 dataset with python?

Tags: python, database, hdf5, h5py

Imagine there is a hdf5 file with float values (1 day interval; for example temperature) for February 2016 and April 2016 and I want to add data for March 2016 afterwards.

This could look like this (in the hdf5 dataset):

```
01-02-2016   5.6
02-02-2016   6.6
...
28-02-2016   7.0
01-04-2016   7.1
...
30-04-2016   9.2
```

Now I want to add the data for March in between using the h5py library with python.

What I currently do:

1. Load dataset
2. resize the dataset (maxshape is set to (None, 2)), so if the shape was (58, 2) before I would resize it to (89,2) (added 31 days in March).
3. read the data from April to a variable.
4. stack the data from March and April.
5. put the data in the dataset:

   dset[amountOfDaysInFebruary:] = stacked_data_of_march_and_april

The more data exists in the database, the more data I always need to read and save every time I want to insert data in between. Is there any better method to insert data in between without having to go through all the steps I mentioned before?

Comment: Have you considered virtual datasets in HDF5? https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/NewFeaturesVirtualDatasetDocs.html This way there is no need to change the file, but just create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I read about virtual datasets and don't really see how it could help me. I see that it could help if you use more than one hdf5 database and want to combine data out of those, but I just want to insert data into one dataset in between the data, which already exists. Maybe I just don't see how this could be useful. In that case, could you go a little bit into detail?

Comment: Indeed, it will not help if you want to stay with one file. In that case, if you have also dates in the hdf5 table, what is wrong with just adding new data to the end of array and do the sorting in client application? It will be a tiny bit slower, but if the chunks are of size one month, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That is a valid thought that also came to my mind some hours ago. Obviously this makes it slower/harder to read data from, let's say, a full year afterwards if you first have to put together the months. The thing is that reading operations will be much more frequent than the saving operation, which makes it hard to make a decision, but thanks for you effort! It's unfortunate that there is no other easy option to insert data.

Comment: Actually, if you know beforehand that you will eventually need full year data, and how many rows for each date, then you could create a full table initially and just leave some month empty or filled with nan-s initially.

Comment: True, I'll give this a thought although this has one big disadvantage: If you want to check whether data exists for a certain time span (btw it's way more complex than my example in the question), you need to read all of the data and check for NaN's instead of just checking whether certain timestamps exist.

Comment: How do you know if data exists for certain timespan if you do not read it anyway?

Comment: I need to read the timestamps anyways, but not everything else.